# LoRa SX1278 can't set LNA GAIN

Tags: stm32, lora

I'm trying to configure my SX1278 Ra-2 LoRa module via STM32 Nucleo board and ran into a problem.

While I was initializing the LNA register (`0xC`) by writing (`0x23`) -> `0010`(max gain) `0011`(boost on), which is supposed to give me the max gain and boost, after reading that register I receive `0x3`.

Is this normal?

While LoRa SX1278 is in sleep mode it will return `0x3`, without showing 3MSB. However in Standby Mode it reads `0x23` as it is supposed to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While LoRa SX1278 in sleep mode will return `0x03`, without showing 3MSB, in Standby Mode it reads `0x23` as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set `AgcAutoOn` to `0`? Otherwise it will automatically set the `LNAGain` bits.

[Source](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001Rc1/QnUuV9TviODKUgt_rpBlPz.EZA_PNK7Rpi8HA5..Sbo?__hstc=212684107.335b283870230a3c02c91a6312731753.1628430521432.1628430521432.1628430521432.1&__hssc=212684107.1.1628430521434&__hsfp=4150320178):

- page 60:

> When AgcAutoOn=0, the LNA gain is manually selected by choosing LnaGain bits in RegLna.

- page 95:

> Note:
> Reading this address always returns the current LNA gain (which
> may be different from what had been previously selected if AGC
> is enabled.

- Page 96: set bit `3` to `0` in `0x0D` to disable `AgcAutoOn`.
- Page 95: for the Booston/max gain, you need to set bits 0-1 and 5-7. Because of your writing style I suspect you are only writing to the lower ones.